# create cookie in javascript but it wont be created

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

Please i tried to create a cookie from javascript code and set its name = fullname, value = id and expires in one hour but when i checked my browser(chrome) i found that it not exists, so any idea about my code issues

```
function cookie_set(fullname, id) {

    var now = new Date();
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + 1 * 3600 * 1000);


    //document.cookie = "name=" + fullname + "=" + id;
    document.cookie = fullname + "=" + id + "; expires=" + now.toUTCString + "; path=/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got an bug in your code:

```
document.cookie = fullname + "=" + id + "; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still the cookie not exists in chrome

Comment: Can you post the full html/js file(s)?